# Background div images lagging in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have created divs that scroll from left to right or from right to left on the click of a button while updating the image in the background. My programming isn't that great (the ugly code) but it isn't lagging at all on chrome or safari but as soon as I load it on firefox the images reload really slow and the divs start to look distorted. I have given my example with a link to an image but originally I am using multiple local images which switch in the background which are only 200kb (I have not included the switching images code). (Please look at the codepen and switch between firefox and chrome you should be able to see the differences when you press on the buttons. I am on a mac.

```
function leftClick() {
  var images = $(".my-image");
  images.eq(0).insertAfter(images.eq(images.length - 1));
  var numberx = 1;
  var number1 = "1";
  var number2x = numberx + 1;
  var number2 = number2x.toString(); //2
  var number3x = number2x + 1;
  var number3 = number3x.toString(); //3
  var number4x = number3x + 1;
  var number4 = number4x.toString(); //4
  var number5x = number4x + 1;
  var number5 = number5x.toString(); //5
  var number6x = number5x + 1;
  var number6 = number6x.toString(); //6
  var number7x = number6x + 1;
  var number7 = number7x.toString(); //7
  var number8x = number7x + 1;
  var number8 = number8x.toString(); //8
  var number9x = number8x + 1;
  var number9 = number9x.toString(); //9
  var number10x = number9x + 1;
  var number10 = number10x.toString(); //10
  $("#image-" + number1).attr("id", "image-" + number10); //1-->10
  $("#image-" + number2).attr("id", "image-" + number1); //1-->2
  $("#image-" + number3).attr("id", "image-" + number2); //3-->2
  $("#image-" + number4).attr("id", "image-" + number3); //4-->3
  $("#image-" + number5).attr("id", "image-" + number4); //5-->4
  $("#image-" + number6).attr("id", "image-" + number5); //6-->5
  $("#image-" + number7).attr("id", "image-" + number6); //7-->6
  $("#image-" + number8).attr("id", "image-" + number7); //8-->7
  $("#image-" + number9).attr("id", "image-" + number8); //9-->10
  $("#image-" + number10).attr("id", "image-" + number9); //10-->9*/

  var refreshedImages = $(".my-image");
  for (var i = 1; i < refreshedImages.length; i++) {
    var intValue = i.toString();
    var turnOnImage = document.getElementById("image-" + intValue);
    turnOnImage.style.display = "block";
  }
  var turnOffImage = document.getElementById("image-" + "10");
  turnOffImage.style.display = "none";
}
```

My Codepen

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Angatvir/pen/qyYvjY)

Note to add: If I hover above the image in firefox it fixes that image but that is really inconvenient.